# Copy a row value on button click event

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to extract a particular column value and wrote this code with the help of this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8TNra/). But messed up somewhere/ or missing some concept.

Any guidance would help. The code follows

**HTML**

```
<tr class="findVal">
<?php
    include("myIncludeFile");

    $result = mysql_query("myQuery");
    while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<td class=".'hidden-phone hidden-tablet hidden-desktop id'.">".$test['col_nm1']."</td>";
       /*Other table data from database
       ..............................*/ 
       echo"<td>".'<div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="total" id ="total" value="'.$test['col_nm2'].'"">'.$test['col_nm2'].'</label>
         </div>'."</td>";
       echo"<td>".'<button type="submit" id="approve" class="btn btn-success" onclick="checkTotal()">Approve</button>'."</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkTotal() {

        var tr = $(this).closest('.findVal');
        var findID = tr.find('.id').text();
        alert(findID);

  }
</script>
```

N.B :[image]

Comment: You messed up the moment you started to use `mysql_*` functions that are deprecated for over 2 years now and no longer work on PHP 7+ installations..

Comment: Yes, but this is not the issue here. Table data show up fine, *the main question is to extract the `id` from the table `td`*

Comment: Ok. And how exactly are we supposed to tell you what's going wrong if you replaced your actual query with "myQuery"?

Comment: @icecub : Just for the sake of your question I uploaded a working version of my webApp. I hope this would help. **(I only shortened the code for convinience)**

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. `$result = mysql_query("myQuery");` <-- Where is your query? "myQuery" is nothing. It's not valid it all. It won't return anything. It will just give you an error.

Comment: u need not worry about the query, as the resultset is shown clearly. If u could help with the javascript that would be fine :)

Comment: You really should try and move away from deprecated functions. they pose a serious and unnecessary security risk to your application. I'll post an answer to your specific question below

Comment: Will definitely keep in mind not to use deprecated functions @Luke and 'icecub

Comment: Your Javascript code is searching for an element with the class `findVal` which is closest to your button. As far as I can see, there's no element in your code that has this class value. Hence it won't return anything.

Comment: Yes, u are right. I am just a newbie, depending on stack for most of my queries. What can I do here to solve the problem?

Comment: @mustangDC do you only want to extract a single column value? or an entire row?

Comment: Just wrap something around your code with the class. Like `<div class='findVal'> Your html table here </div>`. That should do the trick.

Comment: @mrahmat : Yes, the first one `id`

Comment: @icecub : What about `tr` class, which I already mention, I hope they are the same

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong with your code in general. You can patch a few things up here and there, but you will run into problems eventually. Now I don't mind helping you fixing everything properly, if you're really willing to learn something, but that means I need you to trust me a little bit and spending some time on this. It's your choice :)

Comment: @icecub : Of course, just let me know how do I approach the solution.

Comment: I'm gonna fire up a chat session here. Just click the link and we can move on from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126477/discussion-between-icecub-and-mustangdc).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the important `<tr class="findVal">` before your `<td>`s are added.

The jQuery is searching for an element with the class of `findVal` and assigning that to the vriable `tr`. Then, it searches descendants of that element for the class `id`.

In your first line of your `while` loop, add the `<tr>` that the jQuery is looking for.

```
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr class='findVal'>\n";
```

There are other ways to do this that don't require jQuery or finding parent elements and searching again for their children. Since you are already retrieving the ID from the database, I would just add that as a variable in your button's function and tell your javascript to use that ID. Like so;

```
echo"<td><button type='submit' id='approve' class='btn btn-success' onclick='checkTotal({$test['col_nm1']})'>Approve</button>"</td>";
```

Note that by using double quotes, you can pass variables directly in the echo and they will be evaluated by PHP. `echo "this is the $id"`. When you have things that aren't a simple variable string, it's safest to surround the variable in curly braces to tell PHP to evaluate it together `echo "this is the {$row[1]['id']}"`

Answer (score 0):

ok since you just need to extract the column named `ID`, just set id of the `<td>` and call it with your function, assuming your `ID` is unique

```
<td id="<?= $db_result['id_column']; ?>"><?= $db_result['id_column']; ?></td>
```

and on your `button`:

```
<td><button onclick="checkTotal(<?= $db_result['id_column']; ?>)">Approve</button></td>
```

Finally:

```
function checkTotal(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

ofcourse there are way better methods specially if you wanted to extracted a value that's not as simple and short as ID's, than this one but this can give a quick solution

Answer (score 0):

You can just climb your way back up the DOM tree for this, there's nothing that seems to present an obstacle to that here.

Considering you've got the following structure for a row:

```
TR
 |- td
 |- td
 |- td
 |- td
 |- td
 |- td
 |- td
     |- div
          |- label
               |- checkbox
```

A vanilla-js handler attached to the checkbox might look like this:

```
function onCbClicked(evt)
{
  var clickedElem = this;
  var label = clickedElem.parentNode;
  var containingDiv = label.parentNode;
  var clickedCell = containingDiv.parentNode;
  var containingRow = clickedCell.parentNode;

  var firstCell = containingRow.cells(0);
  var idString = firstCell.textContent;
  alert("Id of clicked row: " + idString);
}
```

Here's a working demo:

```js
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt)}
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}

// useful for HtmlCollection, NodeList, String types
function forEach(array, callback, scope){for (var i=0,n=array.length; i<n; i++)callback.call(scope, array[i], i, array);} // passes back stuff we need



window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 constructTable();
 
 var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type = checkbox]');
 forEach(checkBoxes, function(elem){elem.addEventListener('click', onCbClicked, false);} );
}

function makeTableRow( arrayOf8 )
{
 var tr = newEl('tr');
 for (var i=0; i<6; i++)
 {
  var td = newEl('td');
  td.textContent = arrayOf8[i];
  tr.appendChild(td);
 }
 var div = newEl('div');
 var lbl = newEl('label');
 var input = newEl('input');
 input.type = 'checkbox';
 
 lbl.appendChild(input);
 lbl.appendChild( newTxt(arrayOf8[6]) );
 div.appendChild(lbl);
 var td = newEl('td');
 td.appendChild(div);
 tr.appendChild(td);
 
 td = newEl('td');
 td.textContent = arrayOf8[7];
 tr.appendChild(td);
 
 tr.appendChild( newEl('td') );
 
 var btn = newEl('button');
 btn.textContent = 'Approve';
 td = newEl('td');
 td.appendChild(btn);
 tr.appendChild(td);
 return tr;
}

function onCbClicked(evt)
{
 var clickedElem = this;
 var label = clickedElem.parentNode;
 var containingDiv = label.parentNode;
 var clickedCell = containingDiv.parentNode;
 var containingRow = clickedCell.parentNode;

 var firstCell = containingRow.cells[0];
 var idString = firstCell.textContent;
 alert("Id of clicked row: " + idString);
}

function constructTable()
{
 var tblData = [
      [37,'test','test','test',11,12,132,'CPLAB'],
      [38,'wewq','weqw','qweqwe',22,22,484,222],
      [39,'qwe','qweqw','qweqwe',11,11,121,'saee'],
     ]
 var tgt = byId('tblBody');
 tblData.forEach( function(dat) { tgt.appendChild(makeTableRow(dat)); } );
}
```

```html
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Designation</th><th>Description</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Rate</th><th>Total</th><th>For</th><th>Date/Time</th><th>Action</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='tblBody'>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```